# Bootstrap tokenfield: how can you enforce tokens i.e. Prevent users creating new tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, token

Starightforward question:

Is there a way to only accept tokens you provide via a database? Out of the box, it appears to accept anything between two spaces and creates a token for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as following the docs https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield#and-how-about-limiting-tokens-to-my-typeaheadautocomplete-data